# Kill the idle QTP instances from the QTP license server

Tags: qtp

I want to kill the idle instances of QTP from the QTP license server.

The code should check the idle time of QTP based on which it should kill the process (so that the license can be used optimally).

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.
Sreenisha S

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, and the HP recommended way of doing this is by using a commuter license.  Here are details of this ER which was last updated on 2014-Apr-22:

https://softwaresupport.hp.com/group/softwaresupport/search-result/-/facetsearch/document/KM1387261

> QTP licenses are released after 15 minutes if QTP is not running and there was some problem. You'll only see that in the case of a QTP crash for instance. There is no way to configure/change this behavior QTP should never release a license when it's running on the desktop, not actually running a script, but when the QTPro.exe is listed in the task manager and it's not crashed/hung.

Workaround from the above link:

> It is recommend to use commuter license..